# How to refer to the actual element in foreach?

Tags: c#, iteration

I used the following code to step through an *IEnumerable*.

```
IEnumerable<Thing> things = ...;
foreach (Thing thing in things)
  thing = method(thing);
```

The compiler disagrees with it since I'm referring to *thing* that is the iterating variable. Of course, I intend to affect the underlying object in my list, instead. How do I do that?

For now, I went with the work-around using a numerated iteration but there are two issues there. For one, it's not good coding IMHO. Besides that, it requires me to change my *things* from *IEnumerable* to *IList* (or should I even be using *List*?!), which **will** bite be in my lower back when *things* get big.

```
//List<Thing> things = ...;
IList<Thing> things = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < things.Count(); i++)
  things[i] = method(things[i]);
```

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: If you plan on changing elements within your `IEnumerable` you should convert `ToArray` if the number of elements will stay the same, in my opinion.

Comment: @Luke: If he's trying to change the actual element references in the original collection (rather than what they reference) converting it to an array and then changing the references in the array will still not change the original collection

Answer (score 4):

You can project sequence with Linq:

```
 var transformedThings = things.Select(t => method(t));
```

Comment: I like it, facepalm moment?

Comment: @Oliver well, your implementation of `Select` operator is also good :)

Comment: @Oliver What do you mean by *facepalm* moment? I'm visualizing a huge b__ch-slap of epic proportions. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to run the method on all elements, why don't you transform the whole collection:

```
public IEnumerable<Thing> TransformThings(IEnumerable<Thing> input)
{
    foreach (var thing in input)
        yield return method(thing);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var transformedThings = TransformThings(things);
```

This will transform each element as you iterate over the collection, meaning you don't have to enumerate the whole collection to memory.

**EDIT**

Even SIMPLER:

```
var transformedThings = things.Select(thing => method(thing));
```

Comment: var transformed = things.Select( thing => method(thing) );

Comment: Totally agree!  I had a "duh" moment when I saw @lazyberezovsky's answer.  Modified answer.

Answer (score 1):

Item replacement can be easy done using some collection, for example, array or `List<T>` (as you described) by using `for` loop (not `foreach`).

There is no way to **replace the object** using `foreach` statement.

If you really want to use `IEnumerable<T>` interface there are two alternatives:

1. **Transform the sequence** of `Thing`s (see `IEnumerable<T>.Select()` method). The source sequence and source instances of `Thing` **are not modified** in this case.

   For example:

   ```
   var newThings = things.Select(t => new Thing(/* pass different values using original t instance */));
   ```
2. **Update the state** of each instance:

   ```
   class Thing
   {
       public void UpdateState(/* parameters */)
       {
           // Update field/property values, etc.
       }
   }

   ...        

   foreach (var thing in things)
       thing.UpdateState(/* new values */);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

you cant change the references when iterating items inside list since its restricted in enumerators but you can change objects inside items....

use powerful LINQs or just clone your list like ToList() or ToArray().

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the `IEnumerable` will reamin the same, I would use `ToArray()` and iterate with a `for` loop.

For example:

```
char[] chars = "somestring".ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
{
  chars[i] = SomeMethod();
}
```

For modifying something in the collection.

```
Thing[] things = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < things .Length; i++)
{
  AddOne(ref things[i]);
}

public void AddOne(ref Thing t)
{
  t.Foo += 1;
}
```